# SQL Server FileTable weird behavior in cluster environment

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, filetable, sqlfilestream

We have enabled the `Filetable` feature in our SQL Server Cluster environment. Whenever one node fails, SQL Server automatically fails over to a different node but the `Filetable` is not getting enabled automatically, users have to go to cluster configruation/manager to enable the `FileTable` on Node 2 (which is active).

Is there any automatic way to enable the `Filetable` feature in cluster environment of SQL Server, even shared folder is not enabled.